# View 3D STEP .stp CAD model in GWT based web application

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, webgl, step

I am trying to make a GWT based web application which will be able to show 3D model from PTC Creo's .stp (STEP file). I am programming in Eclipse.

I started with [Parallax3D](http://parallax3d.org/) framework, and I am able to make simple objects. But I'm stuck with how to parse the .stp file and make objects from that. 
Later I saw that there is plenty of other tools for 3D on Web. There are "gwt-g3d", "gwtgl", "gwto3d",....

I also found [JSDAI](http://www.jsdai.net/) API, which should be able to parse .stp files. With very limited examples I couldn't manage to do anything usefull.

I am lost with all those things. Which path should I take?

Has anyone done that before OR is there a simpler opensource solution for that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the NIST STEP File Analyzer (free but not open source) to convert the STEP file to VRML/X3D.   Three.js based frameworks can then view the VRML/X3D.   If you want a completely open source solution, you need something to transform the STEP file, which often contains NURBS trimming that three.js lacks, to a tesselated form.   FreeCAD, pythonOCC, node-occ or the underlying OpenCasCade can transform STEP to a mesh form.